# Process still alive after docker kill container

Tags: python, docker

I use docker to run python programs, when I killed container by "docker kill container name"

Some processes are still alive , and got nothing using "docker ps"

Did someone encounter this situation ?

Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

ContOS 
 Linux 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64

Comment: does `docker ps -a` show up anything?
Also please provide more information - how does your `Dockerfile` look like, what commands did you execute.

Comment: This sounds like a docker bug unless you've used docker options to start the container with the same process I'd namespace as the host. I don't know but there's a chance perhaps that if you do that, docker may not configure a cgroup for the container and then if the main container process forks and disowns its child, it may not be killed

Comment: @Martin thank for your reply , actually I run a java process to execute shell to run docker official tensorflow image (exactly run python) and I can see containers are really running with "docker ps" ,    so I also use java execute shell to kill docker container, when the container has been killed , the python process still running

Comment: @Chunko I think you are right , I start container use a outside docker java process that may start one more containers on same host.